# How to use import a module from typescript file within jest test file

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I use `jest` to test my `typescript` codes.

```
import ClassA from '../classA';
jest.mock('../classA');
```

When I `import` a `class` from my `classA.ts` file, `jest` gives me an error:

```
export default ClassA;
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

here is my `jest` config in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/jest": "^19.2.3",
  "jest": "^20.0.4",
  "ts-jest": "^20.0.4",
  "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
  "typescript": "^2.3.2"
},
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    ".(ts|tsx)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "json"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["vue-typescript-import-dts"],
}
}
import Child = require('./child.vue')
import * as Child from './child.vue'
```

```html
npm install vue-typescript-import-dts --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching ts-jest in favor of just copying/pasting this code into a file on my project  [fb ts jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/examples/typescript/preprocessor.js). However, I did have to add one bit to the code to get es6 modules to work in the jest tests.

add

```
|| path.endsWith('.js')
```

to the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to `true` in `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 0):

```html
import { ClassA } from '../classA';
```

Comment: Attach documentation with your answer please